# Different Styling for Captions on Two Different Nivo Sliders on One Page

Tags: nivo-slider

I am trying to put two Nivo sliders on one page. Some of the attributes are different. So I have simply created two scripts for these attributes, "slider" and "slider2". That's no problem.

However, I want to make the title style a little different for the second slider. I noticed that the text style of the slide title is controlled by this style:

```
.nivo-caption p {
 padding:8px;
 margin:0;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 16px;
 }
```

However, I don't see that css style called within my html. (When I look at the web page source code I see it but not when I'm actually looking at the code file itself.)

I'd love to simply create a new style for my second slider, something like:

```
.nivo-caption2 p {
 margin:0;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 12px;
 }
```

But I need to know how to actually call that within my html. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out. Since I have ids of "slide" and "slide2" for each slide show, I simply appended that to my new style and that worked.